# Magento Cart Inclusive Price

Tags: php, magento, cart

How do i get the magento total cart inclusive price?
I found something like this:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$_priceIncludingTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice());
```

but it only gets the price per product which i want is the total inclusive price in the cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this methods to display subtotal with inclusive of tax

```
$this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotal()->getValueInclTax();
```

if you are outside of cart page then use below steps

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartGrossTotal = 0;
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
 $cartGrossTotal += $item->getPriceInclTax()*$item->getQty();
}
echo $cartGrossTotal;
```

Comment: hello mufaddal how to get total price including tax using "Mage" with out using $this..

Comment: Where are you display this price?

Comment: i want to display price including tax from magento root folder and i am including "Mage.php" file. please help me.